# Question on Lightning Design System marked as off-topic

Tags: discussion

I do not understand why my question
[mCustomScrollbar not working when Locker Service is enabled in Salesforce-1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140406/mcustomscrollbar-not-working-when-locker-service-is-enabled) has been put on hold as "off-topic" by [Tushar Sharma](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/11239/tushar-sharma), [Himanshu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/17316/himanshu), [Vigneshwaran G](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/20832/vigneshwaran-g), [dphil](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/3923/dphil).

As of now, the **default slds-scroll will not work in Salesforce-1** application (That's even mentioned in the SLDS webpage).

But should that confine us to not develop contents exceeding the device screen?

My question is regarding an external plugin which I've used in my Lightning app to enable scroll, which works fine when LOCKER SERVICE IS DEACTIVED and which throws an error when LS is active.

Also, I've requested to know the ETA on fixing the much required **slds-scroll** which is not yet compatible in mobile devices, including tablets.

I agree that Salesforce hasn't authorized in their official website to use mCustomScrollbar to enable scroll in the application.
But my question is very SPECIFIC to why it's throwing error when initializing the same when LS is activated.

Why is such a basic and crucial feature not given due importance nor provided with any workaround? 
And it would be a great help if someone could provide any insights on why my question has been marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it was explained well in the comments:

> Would you mind highlighting your exact, specific question and the answer you're looking for ? Please consider that no one here can give any ETA on salesforce internal developments.

I recommend you remove all questions about when these issues will be fixed. As for your specific question, it is maybe a little hard to tell what exactly you're asking. If you make it more clear within the first few paragraphs, that would help. Also, try to narrow down the error to a specific line number.

Your question will be especially well formed if you can provide steps for **Minimum Viable Reproduction**, so anyone could take a small amount of code from your example and drop it into their own org. The smaller the amount of code that must be copied to reproduce, the better your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AdrianLarson for the response. I've edited the question again and removed portion of the question where I asked ETA on slds-scroll fix issue. Please pardon me for doing the same. There was a requirement for me to use the scroll functionality. And since Salesforce hasn't given any updates so far, I included in the question. Anyway, I've removed that part of the question and has made the question more specific. Once again thank you for pointing out the mistake.